# Duplicate entry for key primary mysql Error MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv

He decidido actualizar la pregunta porque el problema es parecido al anterior, pero ahora creo que es mejor mirar el código en su globalidad. Veamos. Quiero insertar eans (un código de 13 dígitos) con PHP en una BBDD MySQL. Los eans salen de un CSV.
Este es el código:

```
<?php

require_once "connection-mysql.php";
$truncate="TRUNCATE TABLE articulos_csv";
$ejecucionTruncate=mysqli_query($conWebService, $truncate);

if(!$ejecucionTruncate){
    echo "Error: ". $sql ."<br>". mysqli_error($conWebService) ."<br>";
    }

/*Si hay letra fuera.
Quitar espacios.
Si hay coma fuera
Si no vienen con 13 caracteres, meter 0 a la izquierda hasta que sean 13 caracteres.


*/




$archivo=fopen("articulos_erp.csv", "r"); //abro el archivo   
$arrayLineasDefinitivo=array();


while(!feof($archivo)){ //Voy leyendo el CSV

    $linea=utf8_encode(fgets($archivo)); //Leo datos con CSV y lo voy poniendo en formato UTF8
    $arrayLineas=explode(";", $linea); //Aquí tengo mi array con los datos del CSV

    if(!empty($arrayLineas[0])){ //Con esto quito cuando el ean esté vacío
        if(!preg_match("/[A-Za-z]/", $arrayLineas[0])){ //Con esto quito los ean que tengan alguna letra
                if(!preg_match("/,/", $arrayLineas[0])){ //Con esto quito las comas
                   
                    $arrayLineasSinEspacios=trim($arrayLineas[0]);
                    $arrayLineasLimpio=str_replace(" ", "", $arrayLineasSinEspacios);
                    $numeroCaracteres=strlen($arrayLineasLimpio);
                    $arrayDigitosDeterminado=array();
                    $arrayLineasLimpisimo=array();
                    $arrayDigitosFinal=array();

                    if(strlen($arrayLineasLimpio)==13||strlen($arrayLineasLimpio)==12||strlen($arrayLineasLimpio)==11){
                        if(!empty($arrayLineasLimpio)){
                            $arrayDigitosDeterminado=$arrayLineasLimpio;
                            $numerodigitos=strlen($arrayDigitosDeterminado);

                            switch($numerodigitos){

                                case 13:
                                    $arrayLineasLimpisimo=$arrayDigitosDeterminado;
                                    break;
                                case 12:
                                    $arrayLineasLimpisimo="0".$arrayDigitosDeterminado;
                                    break;
                                case 11:
                                    $arrayLineasLimpisimo="00".$arrayDigitosDeterminado;
                                    break;  

                            }

                            $valorEan=substr($arrayLineasLimpisimo, 0, 4);

                            if($valorEan!=0000){
                                $arrayDigitosFinal=$arrayLineasLimpisimo;
                                // $contador=0;

                                // echo "<pre>";
                                // var_dump($arrayDigitosFinal);
                                // echo "<br>";
                                // echo "</pre";
                                // $contador++;

                                // echo "El contador final es de".$contador;
                                // var_dump($contador);
                                    // $consulta="SELECT ean FROM articulos_csv WHERE ean=".$arrayDigitosFinal;
                                    // $resultado=mysqli_query($conWebService, $consulta);

                                    // if(!$resultado){
                                        
                                        $sql="INSERT INTO articulos_csv (`ean`) VALUES ('$arrayDigitosFinal')";
                                        $resultado=mysqli_query($conWebService, $sql);
                                        // $contador++;
                                        // $sql="INSERT IGNORE INTO articulos_csv (`ean`) VALUES ('$arrayDigitosFinal') WHERE NOT IN (SELECT `ean` FROM articulos_csv WHERE ean=".$arrayDigitosFinal.")";
                                        
                                        if(!$resultado){
                                            echo "Error: ". $sql ."<br>". mysqli_error($conWebService) ."<br>";
                                            }

                                        
                                    // }

                                   


                            }


                        }
                            
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }  

    //   $sqltruncate="TRUNCATE TABLE articulos_csv";
    //   $resultado=mysqli_query($conWebService, $sqltruncate);
  
    //   if(!$resultado){
    //       echo "Error: ". $sql ."\n". mysqli_error($conWebService);
    //   } 
  
        
    //   $sql="INSERT INTO articulos_csv (`ean`) VALUES ('$arrayLineasDefinitivo[$contador]');";
    //   $resultado=mysqli_query($conWebService, $sql);
    //   $contador++;
  
    //   if(!$resultado){
    //       echo "Error: ". $sql ."\n". mysqli_error($conWebService);
    //   }  

    // }

    // $contador=0;
    // $longitud=count($arrayLineasDefinitivo);
    // $valor=0;

    // while($contador<$longitud){
    //   $valor=$arrayLineasDefinitivo[$contador];

    //   if (!empty($valor)) { //Le meto otro control para campos vacíos
    //     $sql="INSERT INTO articulos_csv (`ean`) VALUES ('$valor');";
    //     $resultado=mysqli_query($conWebService, $sql);
    //     $contador++;
    
    //     if(!$resultado){
    //         echo "Error: ". $sql ."<br>". mysqli_error($conWebService) ."<br>";
    //     }
    //   }
    // }



?>

<!-- //^[0-9]{13}$/g -->
```

El código lo he revisado varias veces y no le veo el error. Ahí hay un ejemplo del error que da:

```
Error: INSERT INTO articulos_csv (`ean`) VALUES ('0711719845652')
Duplicate entry '0711719845652' for key 'PRIMARY'
Error: INSERT INTO articulos_csv (`ean`) VALUES ('4039784916494')
```

En la BBDD dónde se está metiendo, la estructura es la siguiente:

```
ean VARCHAR(20) utf8_spanish_ci nulo:no Primary Key Cardinalidad: 61726
```

Pues el problema es el siguiente: el CSV tiene unos 60K eans. Por tanto, es imposible que me meta 61K, porque además he limpiado todos los incorrectos. Calculo que eans limpios debería meter en torno a 50-55K. Pero además, el tema es que cada vez que me meto en la tabla de la BBDD, cada vez tiene un número de eans distintos. Incluso metiéndome con una diferencia de un segundo, tiene 50K, 80K, 65K... No tiene ningún sentido. Pero yo no veo en qué estoy fallando. ¿Alguna idea? Gracias.

ACTUALIZACIÓN:

Al ejecutar lo de SHOW CREATE TABLE esto es lo que me muestra:

```
CREATE TABLE `articulos_csv` (
 `ean` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ean`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115828/discussion-on-question-by-sergio-duplicate-entry-for-key-primary-mysql-error-mys).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para este caso, puedes usar el modificador `IGNORE` en tu sentencia SQL.

Por ejemplo:

```
$sql="INSERT IGNORE INTO `articulos_csv` (`ean`) VALUES ('$arrayDigitosFinal');";
```

Te dejo aquí lo que dice el [Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html) sobre este modificador:

> If you use the IGNORE modifier, ignorable errors that occur while
> executing the INSERT statement are ignored. For example, without
> IGNORE, a row that duplicates an existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY
> value in the table causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is
> aborted. With IGNORE, the row is discarded and no error occurs.
> Ignored errors generate warnings instead.
>
> IGNORE has a similar effect on inserts into partitioned tables where
> no partition matching a given value is found. Without IGNORE, such
> INSERT statements are aborted with an error. When INSERT IGNORE is
> used, the insert operation fails silently for rows containing the
> unmatched value, but inserts rows that are matched. For an example,
> see Section 23.2.2, “LIST Partitioning”.
>
> Data conversions that would trigger errors abort the statement if
> IGNORE is not specified. With IGNORE, invalid values are adjusted to
> the closest values and inserted; warnings are produced but the
> statement does not abort. You can determine with the mysql_info() C
> API function how many rows were actually inserted into the table.

---

> Si usa el modificador `IGNORE`, se ignoran los errores ignorables que
> se producen al ejecutar la instrucción `INSERT`. Por ejemplo, sin
> `IGNORE`, una fila que duplica un índice `UNIQUE` existente o un valor
> de CLAVE PRIMARIA en la tabla provoca un error de clave duplicada y la
> declaración se aborta. Con `IGNORE`, la fila se descarta y no se
> produce ningún error. En su lugar, los errores ignorados generan
> advertencias.
>
> `IGNORE` tiene un efecto similar en las inserciones en tablas
> particionadas donde no se encuentra ninguna partición que coincida con
> un valor dado. Sin `IGNORE`, dichas instrucciones `INSERT` se cancelan
> con un error. Cuando se usa `INSERT IGNORE`, la operación de inserción
> falla silenciosamente para las filas que contienen el valor no
> coincidente, pero inserta filas que coinciden. Para ver un ejemplo,
> consulte la [Sección 23.2.2, “Particionamiento de LIST”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-list.html).
>
> Las conversiones de datos que desencadenarían errores abortan la
> declaración si no se especifica `IGNORE`. Con `IGNORE`, los valores no
> válidos se ajustan a los valores más cercanos y se insertan; Se
> producen advertencias pero la declaración no se cancela. Puede
> determinar con la función de la API de C [`mysql_info()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/mysql-info.html) cuántas
> filas se insertaron realmente en la tabla.
>
> Para obtener más información, consulte [el efecto de `IGNORE` en la
> ejecución de instrucciones](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#ignore-effect-on-execution).

### Postdata

En el enlace del final podrás ver qué efecto produce el uso de `IGNORE` y decidir cuando conviene usar este modificador y cuando no. Por ejemplo, yo no lo usuaría en inserciones masivas donde me interese tener más o menos controlada **la secuencia de una columna auto incremental en la tabla**, porque su uso no evita que la secuencia se incremente ante intentos fallidos. En ese caso, yo verificaría la existencia del registro antes de insertarlo.

Comment: Probé con el IGNORE, no me acababa de funcionar y he completado la pregunta con más información, a ver si alguno veis el fallo. Muchas gracias.